# How to register a model in django-tagging anywhere not in the applications?

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to register a model in django-tagging not in tagging app, nor in my app?

The standard way is to edit apps/myapp/models.py this way:

```
from apps import tagging
tagging.register(MyModel)
```

I want to keep both applications without changes, for example, to be able to pull new versions and just replace them. So I tried putting this into project settings.py, in the end, but of course this fails.

```
from apps.myapp.models import MyModel
from apps import tagging
tagging.register(MyModel)
```

(This fails when importing MyModel.)

Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in settings.py, as the models haven't been set up yet. One possibility is to do it in urls.py - `admin.autodiscover` is already there, so this might be a good place for the call to `tagging.register` as well.

There has been quite a lot of discussion in the django-developers group about the correct place for this sort of thing, but as yet no firm policy has been reached.